# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind error while trying to close a listener

Tags: java

I'm getting a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind` error when I'm trying to close a listener. Here's my code in opening the listener.

```
SMPPServerSessionListener sessionListener = new SMPPServerSessionListener(newPort);
```

and here is my code closing it.

```
    public String getCloseConn() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("porttt: " + newPort);
    SMPPServerSessionListener sess = new SMPPServerSessionListener(newPort); 
    sess.close();

    return "";
}
```

What my program does is ask the user for port number and start it on submit. Then I'm trying to close the listener when the user click the "Stop Server" button triggering the `getClossConn()` method but I'm getting the error I mentioned earlier. Help please. 
*PS*: Please don't be harsh on me I'm just new here :)

Comment: Why are you attempting to _open_ a new session in your close method?  If the server session is already open and you try to open another one on the same port you will get exactly the error you are seeing.

Comment: @JimGarrison hi sir is this the line you're talking about? `SMPPServerSessionListener sess = new SMPPServerSessionListener(newPort); ` .I thought in this line I was calling the active session and then `sess.close()` to close it. Am I not doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be calling

```
SMPPServerSessionListener sess = new SMPPServerSessionListener(newPort);
```

expecting to get the existing listener.  That statement attempts to create a NEW listener, on the same port as the existing listener, which results in the error you are seeing.

You should pass in a reference to the existing session to the close method and close *that* instead.